# angular2 toggle DOM element

Tags: angular, events

I am working on an Angular project. How do I toggle on a DOM element like jQuery does:

$( ".target" ).toggle();

My goal is to hide children element's content when parent was clicked

How can I do this in Angular?

Comment: Use (click) event on parent to set a component varaible say `let showContent = true` then on the child element use  `*ngIf="showContent"` or use `[hidden]="showContent"`. Using *ngIf is preferable.

Comment: here is what I'am doing :                                                                                                                                                                 visible: boolean = true;
    toggle(event:any) {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
    }                                                                                                      
         <label  (click)="cptFictifToggle($event)">                                       
             <ul class="nav nav-list tree" *ngIf="visible"> </ul>             
         </label>

Comment: But is not working what I'am doing wrong please

Comment: cleaned up wording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component define visible as array of boolean.

```
let visible: Array<boolean> = [];
```

and define the toggle function as:

```
Toggle(i) {
    this.visible[i] = !this.visible[i];
}
```

and in html

```
<ul class="nav nav-list" *ngFor=" let compte of comptes; let i=index" (click)="Toggle(i)">
    <li class="active" *ngIf="visible[i]" >{{compte}}</li>
</ul>
```

Also, push the values to visible array where you get the values of comptes.

```
for (let compte of comptes) {
    this.visible.push(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not manipulate the DOM in your component. Never. It will be the source of a lot of problems.

Your template should only be updated by Angular thanks to binding and change detection.
For that use a variable to maintain the visibility state of your element.

In your template :

```
<div [hidden]="!visible">
  Lorem ipsum...
</div>
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

In your Component

```
class MyComponent {
  visible: boolean = true;

  toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: its working but I forgot to mention that I load my DOM element with Ngfor so  in this case , when I clicked on first looping   parent element my goal its only to close only its children element . please how can I restricted clik action or  stop propagtation only on first children

Comment: You need to have a visible value for each element. I do not know how are structured your data, but when you do your loop, each item of the collection could have a visible property.

Comment: I understand  what your are talking about  but how to append  this visible value  on DOM and processing it to angular side ?

Comment: I'am trying to use index of Ngfor like this   <ul class="nav nav-list"  *ngFor=" let compte of  comptes; let i=index" (click)="Toggle(i)">   toggle(index:number) {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
    } but this not working

Comment: No it does not work. The variable visible is the same for all elements generated by ngFor. You can either define visible as a boolean array, or add move the visible property to the compte objects.